# creating, manipulating, load a large numpy array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, out-of-memory

I am trying to create a large numpy array, say

```
S=0.5
a=np.random.normal(size=(100000,10000))
x=np.maximum(S-a,1)
#This is just an example. The calculation is more complicated than this.
```

But it is too large for the memory. After creating this array, I also need to do manipulation, and use it as training data in machine learning( eg, xgboost, or CART).

So my questions are : 1.How would I create such a big array without getting a memory error and could let me do calculations as well? Could you recommend some packages or links I could learn to do this please? 2. Suppose this array is already saved in a file. How do I load it and then train my model without causing memory error?

I have read
<https://pythonspeed.com/articles/mmap-vs-zarr-hdf5/ >
but it didn't say how to write data onto disk.
Anyone could help please? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

[Dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array.html) can help with large NumPy arrays, but they do not support all functions of NumPy API.

Comment: Hi, Thanks . Will check out. Btw, are you familiar with Pytables? Would that work?

Comment: No, I haven't heard of it. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned in your question that your final target is to use the data for training a machine learning model lets look at the problem from the other end.

**Assuming** that you somehow managed to load the data into memory how do you plan to pass it over to the underlining ML models ? Most of the available classical ML models work on Numpy arrays, so even if you manage to load the data is some format you cannot pass it on to the ML model to train it using those representations until unless they are numpy arrays.

In case your data is sparse you can store them in sparse numpy arrays and some classical models can handle sparse numpy arrays.

This is the general case when data is very large to be fit into memory. Ideally you have to look at ML models which can be trained on a batch at a time. This way you can load a batch of data and train one batch at a time. Any ML model which can be trained using gradient decent algorithm can be trained on a batch at a time. Deep learning models are trained using gradient decent and so they all work on batch of data at a time.

So if you decide to use deep learning models, you normally will end up writing a data loader which will load a batch of data at a time.

**If you do not want to use the batch based training models:**

Bottom line is, since your final target it to train a ML model, first find out the data representation of the ML model you want to use then try to solve your problem of fitting the data into that format. It will be waste of your time and effort to figure out how to fit the data into memory and then realize that your ML model can not work on that representation.

Comment: thanks a lot for reply. But your assumption is my major question at the moment and I need to do some calculation first before I train the model. And my data is not sparse matrix in my example.